# How to use mysql with cmd

Tags: mysql, wampserver

Am actually new to php and mysql programming. I don't knowh how to use mysql with command prompt and wamp server. I was asked to go to the cmd and type mysql, then press enter, but the result I see here is an error.

I went to my cmd, and typed mysql. The result was "mysql is not recognised as an internal or external command..." I also tried c:/wamp/bin/mysql and I saw the same error

Please what am I supposed to do?

Comment: I went to my cmd, and typed mysql. The result was "mysql is not recognised as an internal or external command..." I also tried c:/wamp/bin/mysql and I saw the same error

Answer (score 3):

WAMPServer provides a menu item that will launch you into a command prompt and run the mysql.exe processor.

```
left click wampmanager -> MYSQL -> MYSQL Console
```

If you have not changed the `root` users password, just hit enter when challenged for a password, if you have changed the password enter it at the prompt and then hit enter

Answer (score 0):

Probably the MySQL folder is not on your path.
Just go to your WAMP installation folder and search for the bin folder.
On my setup it look something like `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.20\bin`
Just open your command line in the folder and type `mysql -u<USERNAME> -p<PASSWORD>` to enter the MySQL console.

If you need to use the command a lot, you can add it to your path.

Hope it will help
Liron

Comment: **Never ever for any reason** add anything in WAMPServer **permanantly to your Windows PATH environment variable**. It totally destroys the ability to switch versions of Apache, PHP and MYSQL quickly and simply

Comment: @RiggsFolly There's a sentence that says "never say never..." - Maybe for you it's not preferable, but for other that involve log period of dev on same setup (MySQL / PHP / Apache) when lots of command line work using mysqladmin / mysql / mysqldump it may be much more comfortable.

I do agree that when ever you do a global setup you MUST be aware of the affects it has.

Comment: Suggestion: Write a little batch file that amends the PATH with a `PATH=%PATH;C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.x\bin;C:\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z` and place this in a folder ALREADY on the PATH. Run it from any command prompt you use if you need access to any of wamp executables